# What should I do when I have this error:var opts = Object.create(options || null)?

Tags: node.js, express

I wrote a small server and I got this:

```
//const http = require('http');

const cors = require('cors');

const path = require('path');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const knex = require('knex');

const favicon = require('express-favicon');

const connection = knex({    
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host        : '0.0.0.0',
        port        : '7777',
        user        : 'root',
        password    : 'mypassword',
        database    : 'app',
        
        multipleStatements  : true, 
    },
})


const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'public'));

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));

app.use(express.json()); 

app.use('/api', require('./api')({
    connection,
}));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {

    console.log(`Server is running on ${process.env.HOST}:${port}`)

});
```

And I recived this:

> /mnt/c/users/marce/PROJEKTY/marcels-app/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:48
> var opts = Object.create(options || null)
> ^
>
> TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: public
> at Function.create ()
> at Function.serveStatic [as static] (/mnt/c/users/marce/PROJEKTY/marcels-app/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:48:2

What I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `static` [has to be an object](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), not a string. If you want serve the folder `public` inside `__dirname` then do

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

which will pass the whole path as the first argument.

---

You can easily reproduce this error directly:

```js
Object.create('public');
```